# What does it mean that my GPU is running 0 ops per second

Tags: power-management, gpu

I am currently running an Ubuntu 12.04 laptop built by System76.  I fired up powertop, which I do frequently because my battery life on this machine is attrocious, and I noticed a line at the top which concerns me:

Summary: 594.2 wakeups/second,  0.0 GPU ops/second and 0.0 VFS ops/sec

Specifically, that 0.0 GPU ops per second.  Doesn't most of X run in the GPU these days?  Could this indicate that maybe my GPU is in some way disabled (which would indicate why Psychonauts was unplayable on this system) and (even more importantly to me) that battery is being wasted on doing video operations in the processor?

According to lspci, here is my video controller.  I'll need some pointers on where else to find useful information.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Comment: First, check what tells "Details" in the system preferences. If in the graphic card section there nothing or unknow or something like that, it means the system is not able to get informations from the GPU. You may need to install specific package to have informations on the GPU use, temperature, etc. It is often provided with nVidia and AMD restricted driver, not with the Intel open driver.

Comment: Intel Sandybridge Mobile.  However, what you are saying seems to mean that while powertop is not getting data, the graphics card is probably still working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bug

For more details check [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/powertop/+bug/834725).